# Log4j2 configuration file location dynamically set at runtime

Tags: spring, properties, configuration, runtime, log4j2

I am trying to configure Log4j2 to pick up a configuration file location from a property file outside the deployed .war.  I need to set the location of the external property file at runtime so I am passing the following -D argument to my Tomcat:

```
-Dapplication.home=file:///C:/dev/env1-home
```

I have an application.properties file in the env1-home directory listed above and the various properties are picked up by the spring container and used throughout the application.  One of the properties is:

```
application.log4j.config=C:/dev/env1-home/log4j2.xml
```

I would like to feed that application file property into a context parameter in the web.xml, but the following value in the web.xml:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>$${sys:application.log4j.config}</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Gives me the following error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unable to access file:/C:/dev/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.31-8090/bin/$%7Bsys:application.log4j.config%7D
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dev\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-8.5.31-8090\bin\${sys:application.log4j.config} (The system cannot find the file specified)
...
```